# Error While Enabling Code-First Migrations On Mobile Services Database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Mobile Services project (C# backend) that I recently created and attached to an Azure SQL database. I have been trying to enable Code-First Migrations on that backing database, but it throws errors when I try to update the database.

I ran through all of the conventional steps to enable migrations (Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration). But when I try to Update-Database, it returns the following error:

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.Appointments'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.Appointments' before creating another.

Why is this happening? There aren't any tables in my database, and the project is pretty much the default.

Answer (score 11):

Several of the answers about deriving from a custom entity class will work, but they are not the ideal solution.  As the EF team (and others) have mentioned, you need to simply add this line to your Context Configuration constructor.

```
 SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
```

This will remove your errors when creating migrations and allow you to update the database via powershell command.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had been deploying the app to the server many times and had deleted all the tables to start all over - before this error suddenly occured. So adding this line and redeploying again worked just fine - after that all my tables got recreated. Thank you.

Comment: This goes in your "Configuration.cs" file.
internal sealed class Configuration :
DbMigrationsConfiguration<xx.Service.Models.xxContext>
 {
  public Configuration()
  {
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
   SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new 
EntityTableSqlGenerator());
  }

Answer (score 9):

If you are getting this error on update-database after creating the migration class, Then have a look @ your migration class. The migration class will take primary is clustered index. So remove that from the up() method.

**.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id, clustered: false)
                .Index(t => t.CreatedAt, clustered: true);**

If you using it on azure mobile service, do not call 'update-database' manually.
refer http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/

Comment: This no longer links to anything useful. Tried searching on the azure page, but no joy ...

Answer (score 5):

I was fighting with this problem today for a few hours. Until I found this link:

[How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/d323335f17801c5ed3983411d78ce0eb1d9e29c1/articles/mobile-services/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations.md)

If you follow the instructions there, it will definitely work. The main thing is, that the migration will take place, when you hit F5 during a local debugging session.

Comment: This is the correct answer. When I tried the answer below the client would always throw "Bad Request" errors when I would query it, even though I could use Fiddler to pull down data. So I blew away my database, inherited from EntityData and then used the automatic migrations to take care of creating the tables. It works!!!

Comment: Link appears to have moved [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations.md).

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue.

It is caused by the definition of EntityData that is our base class:

```
public class OrgTest : EntityData
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

I replaced EntityData with my own implementation "CustomEntity" where I removed the attribute [Index(IsClustered = true)] on the CreatedAt column:

```
public abstract class CustomEntity : ITableData
{
   // protected CustomEntity();

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    [Key]   
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

and now I inherit from this one:

```
public class OrgTest : CustomEntity   // EntityData
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Probably I will have troubles further on, but for the time being I can create my model!
Hope you can also start like this!

Comment: I ended up just using a Web API project instead. This may well be the correct answer, but I have no way to confirm the solution.

Comment: It works according to the tutorial I posted before. It is important however, to run the project locally (F5) **before** you publish and to make the changes within your WebApiConig class as stated in point 6 of the tutorial and to enable automatic-migrations (Configuration class within your migrations folder). Since I am using this workflow I did not have any further problems, except for one time when the database access rights where not set correctly. But that seems to be fixed as well now.

Comment: I'm having an issue with this, when I try and insert a row into a table using this CustomEntity, I get the following error: `The operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedAt'`

Comment: Do you have any solution? Now I have this kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

See this article:

[avoid nightmares using ef first migration in azure mobile services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/03/28/mobile-services-net-backend-initializers-and-model-updates.aspx)

EntityData define a cluster indext to CreateAt and Id is by default a cluster index, this way it provide an error and you should define only one.

Comment: Note that the article referenced starts with the text: the default initializers have changed somewhat now that .NET backend has reached the "general availability" milestone. You can find the latest info in [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/), which is the article referenced in [awsomedevdesigner's earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23429333/575530).