# Error while running Update-Database telling me that cannot create more than one clustered index on table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration, azure-mobile-services

I am just doing some extra work and developing quite simple Azure Mobile Service. I am trying to enable Migrations in the project, but facing weird problem - I assume I am doing something wrong.

All my Models inherits from **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData** class, as suggested by all tutorials regarding Mobile Services. When I enable Migration, add initial Migration and try to apply it by running

```
Update-Database
```

I am getting error in console:

```
Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'XXX.YYY'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_XXX.YYY' before creating another.
```

When we check documentation ([here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1695.inside-microsoft-azure-sql-database.aspx)) we can find information that indeed, azure sql database can have only one clustered index. Furthermore, when you add primary key, it automatically add one clustered index for itself. That's ok. But then, why EntityData looks like this:

```
public abstract class EntityData : ITableData
{
    protected EntityData();

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index(IsClustered = true)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

As we can see, we have there declaration of Id property which should be primary key + declaration of CreatedAt property with clustered index. When I alter generated migration code and remove for example clustered index from CreatedAt, everything is working fine. But then, next time I will be adding new Migration it will probably again find the difference and try to add that index. I would like to avoid that.

I will appreciate any hints, tips and help!

Tank You!

Darek

Answer (score 3):

Ahh... I found out another quetion which helped me to resolve the issue.

[here is Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23429333/3014958) and [here is an article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/d323335f17801c5ed3983411d78ce0eb1d9e29c1/articles/mobile-services/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations.md) with more details about proper Migrations procedure.

Generally you need to change WebApiConfig implementation a little bit:

- remove `Database.SetInitializer(..)` call from `Register()` function
- in place of that put lines:

  `var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
   migrator.Update();`

Now after running application everything seems to work fine. Also command `Update-Database` is working as expected.